# ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE locking postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, postgresql-9.6

```
DO $$
BEGIN
raise notice '%', (SELECT * from public.clientcalledthisfunction(1,2));
END $$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  public.clientcalledthisfunction(userid1_ integer, userid2_ integer)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
result integer;
BEGIN
result:=(SELECT  * from public.call_updatedata(userid1_, userid2_)) ;
RETURN result;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
End $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.call_updatedata(userid1_ integer, userid2_ integer)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
userdata_1 integer;
userdata_2 integer;
userdata_total integer;
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM public.updatedata(userid1_) INTO userdata_1;

SELECT * FROM public.updatedata(userid2_) INTO userdata_2;

userdata_total:=(userdata_1 + userdata_2);
RETURN userdata_total;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
End $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.updatedata(userid_ integer)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
userdata_ integer;
BEGIN

LOOP
SET  TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN
SAVEPOINT foo;

SELECT userdata FROM public.footable WHERE userid=userid_ INTO userdata_;

UPDATE public.footable SET userdata = userdata_ + 1 WHERE userid=userid_ ;

EXIT ;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT foo;
END;
END LOOP;
RETURN userdata_ + 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Client `calls public.clientcalledthisfunction()` function;

I need to implement   `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` on `SELECT + UPDATE` in `updatedata()` function, because i dont want "lost update"...I want to set SERIALIZABLE isolation level **only** in `public.updatedata function()`.

And in `updatedata()` function if there is an exception; i want it to rollback to `savepoint foo` and retry `select + update` process through loop again...

But i get `error` saying `"control reached end of function without RETURN"`...I can't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to set SERIALIZABLE isolation level only in public.updatedata function().

You can't. Isolation is a transaction-level property.

> And in updatedata() function if there is an exception; i want it to rollback to savepoint foo

You can use a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ...` block for that.

But this wouldn't actually work if you were using serializabile isolation since some serialization failures can only be found at commit time.

Comment: ...."But this wouldn't actually work if you were using serializabile isolation since some serialization failures can only be found at commit time.".....There is no other way to do this? I mean a work around?

Comment: @sommeguyy You haven't clearly explained the underlying problem you are trying to solve, so it's hard to say.

Comment: eventually i solved my problem by using "FOR UPDATE" lock.

Answer (score 0):

In every function you have

```
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
End
```

at the end. If any exception occures then this piece of code fires. And since there is no `return` statement afterwards it crashes with `"control reached end of function without RETURN"` error.

Analyze those exceptions and you will know exactly what is going on. Or even better, simply remove those lines. After all `EXCEPTION WHEN others` is a root of all evil.

---

*EDIT:* After some searching it seems that you can't change isolation level inside a function. After all calling a function is a query and isolation level has to be set before any query.

Comment: if i remove it as you said, then it gives an error saying "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query"

Comment: @sommeguyy Here you go. You have `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;` inside loop. I assume that if you move it outside (i.e. 1 line up) then it should be fine.

Comment: @sommeguyy Right, after some searching it seems that you can't change isolation level inside a function. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274457/set-isolation-level-for-postgresql-stored-procedures After all calling a function is already a query.