# FOR UPDATE lock postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, serialization, locking, postgres-9.6

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.updatedata(userid_ integer)
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE
userdata_ integer;
BEGIN

LOOP
BEGIN
     PERFORM 1 FROM public.footable f WHERE f.userid=userid_ LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE ;
    userdata_:=(SELECT f.userdata FROM public.footable f WHERE f.userid=userid_  );
    UPDATE public.footable f SET userdata = userdata_ + 1 WHERE f.userid=userid_ ;
EXIT ;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
END;
END LOOP;

RETURN userdata_ + 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
END $$ language plpgsql;
```

Can i prevent `"lost update"` issue for userdata column, when i use `"FOR UPDATE"` lock like this?

Actually i wanted to use `serializable isolation` in the first place, but it turns out that in `serializable isolation` some errors can only be detected after commıt([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502974/isolation-level-serializable-locking-postgresql-9-6/41506961#))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will avoid a lost update, but you can achieve the same with a simple SQL statement:

```
UPDATE public.footable f
SET userdata = userdata + 1
WHERE f.userid = userid_
RETURNING userdata;
```

There can be no lost update, because the first `UPDATE` will lock the row in exclusive mode, and any concurrent `UPDATE` will have to wait until the transaction holding the lock is done, and then the result of the first `UPDATE` is visible to the second one.